# creating a loop to find out number of sales within the first 20 days

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp

I am a newbie to py and cannot figure out how to find the number of sales calls 20 days after the FIRST sale. The question is asking me to figure out the percent of sales people who made at least 10 sales calls in their first 20 days. 
Each row is a sales call and the salespeople are represented by the col `id`, the sales call time in recorded in `call_starttime`.

The df is fairly simple and looks like this

```
    id      call_starttime  level
0   66547   7/28/2015 23:18 1
1   66272   8/10/2015 20:48 0
2   66547   8/20/2015 17:32 2
3   66272   8/31/2015 18:21 0
4   66272   8/31/2015 20:25 0
```

I already have counted the number of convos per id and can have filtered out anyone who has not made at least 10 salescall

The code is am currently using is

```
df_withcount=df.groupby(['cc_user_id','cc_cohort']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df_20andmore=df_withcount.loc[(df_withcount['count'] >= 20)]
```

I expect the output to give me the number of ids (sales people) who in their first 20 days made at least 10 calls. As of now I can only figure out how to do made at least 10 calls over all time

Comment: to understand your your question clearly, you were able to group the number of calls made by each user ?

Comment: Yes I can group the number of calls made by each user, but now I need to figure out the number of calls in a certain time period based on the time stamp of the first call the user made

Comment: is it possible for you to post the sample code block ?

Comment: of course see above

Answer (score 0):

I assume that *call_starttime* column is of *DateTime* type.

Let's start from a simplified solution, checking only the **second** call
(not 10 subsequent calls).

I changed slightly your test data, so that person with id = 66272
has the second call within 20 days after the first (August 10 and 19):

```
      id      call_starttime  level
0  66547 2015-07-28 23:18:00      1
1  66272 2015-08-10 20:48:00      0
2  66547 2015-08-20 17:32:00      2
3  66272 2015-08-19 18:21:00      0
4  66272 2015-08-31 20:25:00      0
```

The first step is to define a function stating whether the current
person is "active" (he did the second call in 20 days from the first):

```
def active(grp):
    if grp.shape[0] < 2:
        return False  # Single call
    d0 = grp.call_starttime.iloc[0]
    d1 = grp.call_starttime.iloc[1]
    return (d1 - d0).days < 20
```

This function will be applied to each group of rows (for each person).

To get **detailed** information on activity of each person, you can run:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(active)
```

For my sample data the result is:

```
id
66272     True
66547    False
dtype: bool
```

But if you are interested only in the **number** of active people, use
`np.count_nonzero` on the above result:

```
np.count_nonzero(df.groupby('id').apply(active))
```

For my sample data the result is *1*.

If you want the **percentage** of active people, divide this number by
*df.id.unique().size* (multipied by 100, to express the result in percents).

And now, how to change this solution to check whether a person has made
**at least 10** calls in initial 20 days:

The only difference is that *active* function should compare dates of
calls No *0* and *9*.

So this function should be changed to:

```
def active(grp):
    if grp.shape[0] < 10:
        return False  # Too little calls
    d0 = grp.call_starttime.iloc[0]
    d1 = grp.call_starttime.iloc[9]
    return (d1 - d0).days < 20
```

I assume that source rows are ordered by *call_starttime*.
If this is not the case, call *sort_values(by='call_starttime')* before.

## Edit following your comment

I came up with another solution including grouping by *level* column,
with no requirements on source data sort and with easy parametrization
concerning numbers of initial days and calls in this period.

Test DataFrame:

```
      id      call_starttime  level
0  66547 2015-07-28 23:18:00      1
1  66272 2015-08-10 19:48:00      0
2  66547 2015-08-20 17:32:00      1
3  66272 2015-08-19 18:21:00      0
4  66272 2015-08-29 20:25:00      0
5  66777 2015-08-30 20:00:00      0
```

Level *0* contains one person with 3 calls within first 20 days (August 10, 19 and 29). 
Note however that the last call has later hour than the first, so actually
these 2 TimeStamps are **more** than 19 days apart, but since my solution
clears the time component, this last call **will** be accounted for.

Start from defining a function:

```
def activity(grp, dayNo):
    stDates = grp.dt.floor('d')  # Delete time component
    # Leave dates from starting "dayNo" days
    stDates = stDates[stDates < stDates.min() + pd.offsets.Day(dayNo)]
    return stDates.size
```

giving the number of calls by particular person (group of *call_starttime* values)
within first *dayNo* days.

The next function to define is:

```
def percentage(s, callNo):
    return s[s >= callNo].size * 100 / s.size
```

counting the percentage of values in *s* (a *Series* for the current *level*)
which are >= *callNo*.

The first processing step is to compute a *Series* - number of calls,
within the defined "starting period", for each *level* / *id*:

```
calls = df.groupby(['level', 'id']).call_starttime.apply(activity, dayNo=20)
```

The result (for my data) is:

```
level  id   
0      66272    3
       66777    1
1      66547    1
Name: call_starttime, dtype: int64
```

To get the final result (percentages for each *level*, assuming the
requirement to make **3** calls), run:

```
calls.groupby(level=0).apply(percentage, callNo=3)
```

Note that *level=0* above is a reference to the **MultiIndex level**,
not to the column name.

The result (again for my data) is:

```
level
0    50.0
1     0.0
Name: call_starttime, dtype: float64
```

*Level 0* has one person meeting the criterion (of total 2 people at this
level) so the percentage is *50* and at *level 1* nobody meets the criterion,
so the percentage is *0*.

Note that *dayNo* and *callNo* parameters allow easy parametrization
concerning the length of the "initial period" for each person and
the number of calls to be made in this period.

The computation desrcibed above is for **3** calls, but in your case
change *callNo* to your value, i.e. **10**.

As you can see this solution is quite short (only 8 lines of code),
much shorter and much more "Pandasonic" than the other solution.

If you prefer a "terse" coding style, you can also do the whole computation
in a **single** (although significantly chained) instruction:

```
df.groupby(['level', 'id']).call_starttime\
    .apply(activity, dayNo=20).rename('Percentage')\
    .groupby(level=0).apply(percentage, callNo=3)
```

I added *.rename('Percentage')* to change the name of the result *Series*.

Comment: thanks, this is close to what I want. It helped me a lot. I want to look at the persons first 20 days not just the next 20 calls. So if id"66547" first call was 2015-08-20 17:32:00 I want to see that he made at least 10 calls by Oct 15.... does that make sense?

Comment: nevermind! I got it- thank you so much. now if I want to group by level can I just run a groubby?

Comment: I can't figure out how to group this by level now- aka I want to see which level had how many people who made 10 sales in the first 20 days

Comment: Note that e.g. user *66547* has rows in 2 levels (1 and 2),
so it is not clear how to group by *level* column.
Do you want to make separate counting at each level?
If yes then first group rows on *level* and within each such group
perform computation which I proposed.

Comment: Thanks, that was an error on my part each id only belongs to one level (was a mistake when creating a dummy df).
I want something that tells me 10 people on level 0 fit into the active function we defined.

Comment: A correction to your first comment: If a person made his first call on *2015-08-20* (regardless of time) then his 20-day initial period ends on the end of day on *2015-09-08* (not *2015-10-15*).

Answer (score 0):

I used a Person Class to help solve this problem.

1. Created a dataframe
2. Changed call_start_time from String to TimeDelta format
3. Retrieved 20 days date after FIRST call_start_time
4. Created Person class to keep track of days_count and id
5. Created a list to hold Person objects and populated the objects with data from dataframe
6. Print list of Persons objects if they have hit 10+ call sales within the 20 day time frame from start_date to end_date

I have tested my code and it works good. There can be improvements but my main focus is achieving a good working solution. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import numpy as np

# prep data for dataframe
lst = {'call_start_time':['7/28/2015','8/10/2015','7/28/2015','7/28/2015'],
        'level':['1','0','1','1'],
        'id':['66547', '66272', '66547','66547']}

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

# convert to TimeDelta object to subtract days
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['call_start_time'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['call_start_time'], "%m/%d/%Y").date()

# get the end date by adding 20 days to start day
df["end_of_20_days"] = df["call_start_time"] + timedelta(days=20)

# used below comment for testing might need it later
# df['Difference'] = (df['end_of_20_days'] - df['call_start_time']).dt.days

# created person class to keep track of days_count and id
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id, start_date, end_date):
        self.id = id
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.days_count = 1

# create list to hold objects of person class
person_list = []

# populate person_list with Person objects and their attributes
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # get result_id to use as conditional for populating Person objects
    result_id = any(x.id == row['id'] for x in person_list)

    # initialize Person objects and inject with data from dataframe
    if len(person_list) == 0:
        person_list.append(Person(row['id'], row['call_start_time'], row['end_of_20_days']))
    elif not(result_id):
        person_list.append(Person(row['id'], row['call_start_time'], row['end_of_20_days']))
    else:
        for x in person_list:
            # if call_start_time is within 20 days time frame, increment day_count to Person object
            diff = (x.end_date - row['call_start_time']).days
            if x.id == row['id'] and diff <= 20 :
                x.days_count += 1
                break

# flag to check if nobody hit the sales mark
flag = 0

# print out only person_list ids who have hit the sales mark
for person in person_list:
    if person.days_count >= 10:
        flag = 1
        print("person id:{} has made {} calls within the past 20 days since first call date".format(person.id, person.days_count))

if flag == 0:
    print("No one has hit the sales mark")
```